# UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install opensv3 for Anaconda using the below command

```
conda install -c menpo opencv3
```

But I am getting the below error

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
>    - opencv3
>    - zict

Not sure why `Opencv3` is already there and why `zict` is a problem.

Any way I can uninstall both of them and then probably start fresh installation ?
Or what would be the correct way to resolve this ?'

EDIT: I am on Python 3.6. I have tensorflow and numpy already installed.

Comment: Use this to install `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`.

Comment: relevant? https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4832

Comment: `UnsatisfiableError` seems like an awful meaningless name for an exception

Comment: @Sraw That worked ! (and I've no idea why)

Comment: @PirateX easy, the repo you used is no longer maintained. So it will be a lot of problem.